# What is a Recurrent Heavy Subgraph?

Tags: data-mining, graphs, terminology

I recently came across this term `recurrent heavy subgraph` in a talk. I don't seem to understand what it means and Google doesn't seem to show any good results. Can someone explain what this means in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term may best be expressed as a **Recurrent**, **Heavy** **Subgraph**. That is, a subgraph which is both **Recurrent** *and* **Heavy**.

**Heaviness** of a subgraph refers to heavily connected vertices- that is, nodes which are connected many times ("many" being relative to the network in question).

**Recurrent** refers to the propensity of a subgraph to occur more than once.

Thus, a **Recurrent Heavy Subgraph**  is a densely connected set of vertices which occurs several times in the overall network.

These subgraphs are often used to determine properties of a network.

For example: In a network of emails interactions within a company organized into 4-person teams with one member acting as the lead, each team's email activity (if they email between themselves sufficiently to be considered "heavy") could be described as a **Heavy** **Subgraph**. The fact that these subgraphs occur many times in the network make them **Recurrent Heavy Subgraphs**. If one was searching for structure in the network, noticing that these recurrent, heavy subgraphs exist would go a long way toward determining the organization of the network as a whole.